# Правильное формулирование задачи

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно поставить задачу исполнителю — подготовить письмо на имя Иванова или подготовить письмо Иванову (имеется в виду оформить и направить деловое письмо, в котором обращаются к Иванову)?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант годится, а второй подходит в том случае, если исключено неправильное понимание: подготовить (кому?) Иванову (как будто сам исполнитель Иванов). Чтобы сказать наверняка, нужен полный текст.